# What is Johanna Beckett's maiden name?

Tags: castle

Did any episode of *Castle*, directly or indirectly (references to Kate's grandparents, clips of newspaper articles, etc), give out Johanna Beckett's maiden surname?

If not, was it ever provided in any supplemental material or creator interviews?

Comment: I did quick googling and combining with what I remembers, answer should be No, and No